# How can I make double click event on node in d3.js?

Tags: svg, d3.js

I want to make double click event on nodes.
So I tried

```
.on("dbclick",function(d){return "http://google.com");});
```

and

```
.bind({"dbclick",function(d){alert("hello")} });
```

But all failed. Can anyone help me?

Full codes are below.

```
var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
    .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    //.on("dbclick",function(d){return "http://google.com");});
    //.attr("xlink:href", function(d){return d.url;}
    .call(force.drag);
    //.bind({"dbclick",function(d){alert("hello")} });
```

---

Finally, I used a below method. (dblclick also works)

```
var node = svg.selectAll(".node") .data(graph.nodes) .enter().append("a") 
              .attr("class", "node") .attr("target", "_blank")
              .attr("xlink:href", function(d){return "google.com";;})
```

Comment: This code may have an error `{return http://google.com");}`, right ?

Comment: yes there is mistake, I omitted "

Answer (score 84, accepted):

You can use "dblclick" instead of "dbclick":

```
nodes.on("dblclick",function(d){ alert("node was double clicked"); });
```

Answer (score 3):

If using **D3 Observable**:

```
const nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
        .on("dblclick", d => {
          d3.event.preventDefault();
          // do your thing
        });
```